# Refresh MuliView's view every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

in the clientside pageLoad() function im trying to get the multiview active index and postback to my updatepanel1 after 5 seconds only if active index is 2

following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function pageLoad() {
       if (document.getElementById('MultiViewManage').getAttribute("ActiveViewIndex") == 2) {
          window.setTimeout("__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1','')",5000);
       }
   } 
</script>
```

im getting null exeption or some kind of error what am i doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: You can't access a MultiView on clientside, because it is rendered as a simple div. So you also cannot access attributes(what would be btw. a horrible place to store such properties) to get the ActiveViewIndex.
You should do that all on serverside if possible.

Comment: ok thanks for your replay, so then i have another question how can i register the 5 second postback to pageLoad() from server side when the function already exist

Comment: @Python: clarify(in your question) what you really want to achieve because it's still unclear. You want a 5 second delay before the page posts back if your MultiView's ActiveViewIndex is 2? If true, this seems odd to me, isn't there a more userfriendly way to achieve whatever you want?

Comment: i have an multiview inside an updatepanel and i want to refresh my updatepanel every 5 second but only when specific view is active

Comment: i could have used the ajax timer but i have a weird problem with it postbacks it sometimes stuck alot of time even though i placed the timer outside the update panel

Comment: @python: i would embed all views in separate UpdatePanels beside the outer UpdatePanel. If you switch the view you have to trigger the outer UpdatePanel. But the timer-tick will trigger the inner UpdatePanel that belongs to view with ActiveViewIndex 2.

Comment: @python: if my suggestion works, you should update your queston's subject to something like `Refresh MuliView's view every 5 seconds` so that others can find it. If it doesn't work or it's to     elaborate to change, comment my answer accordingly.

Comment: sorry for the delay i didnt see your message, i have now updated the message. thanks for your time and reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto-refresh your update panel after 5 seconds if user is on MultiView's `ActiveViewIndex=2`, use an ASP.Net Timer in your UpdatePanel that fires an asynchronous postback every 5 seconds. I would embed the content of the view that should be refreshed in a separate UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="5000"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPanelRefresh" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
.....
```

Then refresh the content of your UpdatePanel in Timer_Tick event-handler in codebehind.

I would embed all views in separate UpdatePanels beside the outer UpdatePanel. If you switch the view you have to trigger the outer UpdatePanel. But the timer-tick will trigger the inner UpdatePanel that belongs to view with ActiveViewIndex 2